# Terminal not working properly

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

While I was messing around with stuff, I ran the commands:

```
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
exec -l $SHELL
gcloud components update dns
gcloud auth login
gcloud init
```

After this, my bash PATH (or something – I don't really understand this stuff) changed, and I can't run a lot of things I did before, for example:

```
source activate python3
```

The error that shows up is:

```
-bash: activate: No such file or directory
```

How do I just revert to the settings I had before?

When running `echo $PATH`,

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

is what shows up. I think I need to get rid of the `/opt/X11/bin` part of the path, but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 2):

The `bash exec -l` command *replaced* your current shell session with a newly initialized shell (like a *login*) and that does not contain any of the aliases and temporary symbols which were established with `source activate`.  Perhaps your shell initialization does not set the `PATH` variable in the same way that your ordinary interactive sessions do.

You could do

```
source ~/.bashrc
source activate python3
```

or exit the current shell session, and start over.

Further reading:

- [The exec builtin command](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/exec)
- [What are the uses of the exec command in shell scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351198/what-are-the-uses-of-the-exec-command-in-shell-scripts)
- [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell)